# Does Broken Crown work on Bounty caches?

Tags: diablo-iii

Will wearing a Broken Crown work on Bounty Caches?

[image: When a gem drops, a gem of the type socketed into your helmet also drops]

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the Broken Crown does not work on Bounty Caches even though the text makes it sounds like it could.

I tested this by wearing a Broken Crown with an Emerald while opening Caches.

I got the following gems:

[image: 4 Emeralds and 15 other gems]

If the crown had worked I should have gotten at least the same number of Emeralds as the total number of other gems.

I only got 4 Emeralds and 15 of the other gems.

Comment: @OrcJMR If it had worked it would also have copied the rubies, there by having at least 6 emeralds.

Comment: Dammit. That was some proper brain malfunction on my part, after stopping by after a 11 hour shift... Of course the crown does copy all gems, and does not just double the Emerald drops, like Sage's set does to Death's Breaths. Deleting the comment!  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯